# Dialogflow- chatbot related queries

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I've created a basic app with a chatbot that can respond to what I type using DialogFlow and Angular. It is hosted locally. Now I want to have that chatbot respond to what I type with cards, lists and such. Like how Messenger has templates. I want to have a custom payload sent to me in response to what I send. Can anyone please help me? (NOTE: iam using the v2api)

Comment: You need to custom code all of those features in your angular and you can generate any custom payload which you can easily render in your Frontend. Example => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g1HDNrVNNnQ

Comment: you need to parse the payload and render it into HTML as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Dialogflow supports rich message response to only certain platforms that it has listed on its website for ex. Facebook, google assistance etc. To display rich message you need to code it out.